# CentOS has failed to come back up after a kernel upgrade and reboot - stuck on "trying to load: pxelinux.cfg/default"

Tags: centos, centos6

CentOS 6.8.

I performed a yum update today that updated the kernel, and hence 500 other things. I rebooted the box a while ago and it's not come back up yet. I just logged into an IPMI session to see what's going on and it's stuck after the line

"trying to load: pxelinux.cfg/default"

Can anyone advise me how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a pxe/dhcp/tftp boot server in your environment?  What does your dhcp global config, or host specific config look like?

Comment: Check the boot order in the BIOS. It appears the system is trying to boot from the network.

Comment: OK Sven, thanks.  I'm by no means an expert at this sort of thing, I just run a dedicated server through oneprovider.com (a retired online.net box).  I've certainly not touched the BIOS in any way, all I did was a yum update and a reboot of a previously healthy box.  Any idea what might have caused this?

Comment: Talk to your provider. They will need to fix the PXE server problem.

Comment: I booted manually to HDD and it's fine now, thank you.  I saw a quick message about something being corrupted in the BIOS, but missed it.  I'll reboot in a moment and screenshot it so I can look into it further.  Thank you @Sven

Comment: ..."bios has corrupted hw-pmu resources"...